# python pandas date convertion to words

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a particular format of date in my dataframe as
df:
     Date
  12-Jun-16
  22-Jan-12

I want to covert it to this format 
df:
     Date
  12-Jan-2015

Any help as to how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need convert column [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then if need change format add [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
print (df)
          Date
0  12-Jun-2016
1  22-Jan-2012
```

Comment: I am not able to upvote this but thank you so much! It worked for me. I'd upvote by 2 because I had spent a lot of time just checking for an answer!